# How to use special characters inside php exec

Tags: php, exec, quotes

Can anyone explain how to make this code work?

```
exec("ffmpeg -f concat -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" ./*.mp4) -c copy output.mp4");
```

I've tried to add '\' before " and ', it still didn't work.
Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must escape double quotes and backslashes. You can do it using backslash: *\*

```
exec("ffmpeg -f concat -i <(printf \"file '%s'\\n\" ./*.mp4) -c copy output.mp4");
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. I did what you said before, but it seemed still not working. I got such error - sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Now there's a problem with the command is being executed. Can you test it on a terminal, rather tan running it through PHP?

Comment: ffmpeg -f concat -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" ./*.mp4) -c copy output.mp4      --> This command runs perfect with shell.

Comment: I have edited the answer. I forget escaping a backslash. Please test it again.

Comment: It still doesn't work.  ERROR : sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Answer (score 0):

i know this question is super old but i had the same problem myself and couldn't find the answer anywhere

in case you are having this error on windows, to escape the special characters you have to use ^ instead of backslash

so stuff like

`exec("some_application https://example.com/api.php?arg1=1&arg2=2")`

won't work because of the & character, so it must become

`exec("some_application https://example.com/api.php?arg1=1^&arg2=2")`